# How does a python lambda 'bound variable' work with a returned function value which is in turn passed as another argument?

Tags: python, lambda

I am researching the lambda function, and I came across this code sample:

```
def myfunc(n):
    return lambda a : a * n

tripler = myfunc(3)
print(tripler(10)) # Output: 30
```

I understand that when tripler is assigned to the return value from the myfunc function, the value of 3 is passed as an argument and from within the function, it is represented as 'n'. But lambda uses a bound variable labeled 'a'. So at this point, ignoring the final print line, I'm not sure how 'a' is factored into this. When I run this code, I receive no errors.

I would be interested in understanding how this code is processed and how it comes up with its conclusion without generating errors.

Comment: When you call `myfunc(3)` it returns a lambda function that is essentially: `lambda a : a * 3`. You then call *that function* with `tripler(10)` passing in `10` as `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of `myfunc` is a *closure*, which retains a reference to the argument passed to `myfunc`.

```
>>> x = myfunc(3)
>>> x.__closure__[0].cell_contents
3
```

When you call `x`, the value is used.

```
>>> x(10)  # (lambda a: a * n)(10), with n == 3
30
```

You can see this in the byte code generated for `x`:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(x)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_DEREF               0 (n)
              4 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

`LOAD_FAST` references the local variables (in this case, the only local variable is the parameter `a`), while `LOAD_DEREF` references the closure. The argument `0` is an index into the tuple stored in `x.__closure__`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys! Much appreciated! :) @chepner, once you mentioned 'closure', I immediately googled it and found [this article](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/closure) explaining what closures are and how they work. Now I understand. Good to know! Thanks again! :)